# No tag library could be found with this URI weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl, weblogic

I am working on a spring mvc project with weblogic 10.3.6. However,when I run the application, I am getting this error:

```
login.jsp:2:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

    ^----^
login.jsp:2:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

    ^----^
login.jsp:5:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

    ^----^
login.jsp:5:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

    ^----^
login.jsp:15:6: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__headcommons_tag".
    <imap:headCommons/>

     ^--------------^
login.jsp:15:6: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__headcommons_tag".
    <imap:headCommons/>

     ^--------------^
headCommons.tag:6:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    ^----^
headCommons.tag:6:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I am reading everydat everything I can on the Internet but I could not solve my problem. I need help, What can I do to solve this problem?

I am using jstl 1.2 ,hibernate 4.2.7, spring mvc 3.2.5. and weblogic 10.3.6.0

Comment: i did not install all jars manually.i am using maven.So there is no lib under web-ınf/lib.where should i put libs to prevent conflict ? can you explain more?

Comment: there is no libraries under webapp's /WEB-INF/lib.My all libraries is under external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the JSTL shared libraries provided with WebLogic. These are not installed by default. The installation steps can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP197